# Creating an html dropdown menu using meteor

Tags: html, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create an html dropdown menu using meteor.
I create a select element, then using helpers try to list province names in the dropdown. Here's the **main.html**

```
<template name="signup">   
    <select>
        {{#each province}}
            {{> provinceTemplate}}
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>

<template name="provinceTemplate">
    <option>{{provinceName}}</option>
</template>
```

And this is **main.js**

```
Template.body.helpers({
  province:[
    {provinceName: 'Tehran'},
    {provinceName: 'Isfahan'},
    {provinceName: 'Yazd'},
    {provinceName: 'Shiraz'},
    {provinceName: 'Kerman'},
  ],
});
```

I simply use the helper to shape the dropdown.
But when I run it, there's nothing inside the select tag.

Thank you guys...

Comment: Now I see what is wrong, the problem is that you define your `province` helper in `body` template but you use it in `signup` template. Move the `province` helper to `signup` template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... You shouldn't call a template( {{> TemplateName}} ) in another template... As soon as I took my code out of the first template, it started working.
The following code is wrong...

```
    <body>
        {{> firstTemplate}}
    </body>

    <template name="firstTemplate">
        ...
        {{> secondTemplate}}
        ...
    </template>

    <template name="secondTemplate">
        ...
    </template>
```

Whereas the following code works...

```
<body>
    ...
    {{> secondTemplate}}
    ...
</body>
<template name="secondTemplate">
    ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  province() {
    return [
      {provinceName: 'Tehran'},
      {provinceName: 'Isfahan'},
      {provinceName: 'Yazd'},
      {provinceName: 'Shiraz'},
      {provinceName: 'Kerman'},
    ];
  },
});
```

Comment: Nope... Didn't help! @Khang

Comment: Do you see any error messages on browser console? maybe let try put a `console.log` inside `province` helper function to check if it really run

Comment: The function exists and contains the objects (province names) but again the dropdown contains none of the names and is empty. @khang

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the full `main.html` file? seem like the problem is something different. I just check the Blaze document and realize helper can be a value, so your `main.js` is fine. I need to update my Blaze skill, it seems to get updated recently

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `<select>` inside the `<body>` ? This should work:

**Main.html**

```
<body>

<select>
  {{#each province}}
  {{> provinceTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</select>

</body>

<template name="provinceTemplate">
  <option>{{provinceName}}</option>
</template>
```

**Main.js**

```
Template.body.helpers({
  province:[
    {provinceName: 'Tehran'},
    {provinceName: 'Isfahan'},
    {provinceName: 'Yazd'},
    {provinceName: 'Shiraz'},
    {provinceName: 'Kerman'},
  ];
});
```